# How to prove $\sqrt 2 x + \sqrt {2{x^2} + 2x + 1} + \sqrt {2{x^2} - 10x + 13} + \sqrt {2{x^2} - 22x + 73} \geq \sqrt{157}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, roots, radicals

$$
\quad{\forall x\in \mathbb{R}:\\
\sqrt 2 x + \sqrt {2{x^2} + 2x + 1}  + \sqrt {2{x^2} - 10x + 13}  + \sqrt {2{x^2} - 22x + 73} \geq \sqrt{157}}$$ I want to prove this.I tried to graph it and see whats going on ...https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xgjovvkal6
I also tried to prove it by derivation ,but it become complicated .
Can anybody give me an idea ? I am thankful in advance.

Comment: Where is this inequality from?

Comment: For the first term, do you mean $\sqrt{2\cdot x}$ or $\sqrt{2}\cdot x$?

Comment: @Jack :From an old book, which written by Parviz shariari ,$$\text{ Parviz Shahriari} $$ https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parviz_Shahriari $$$$It is Persian book ,which mean creativity in solving mathematics .

Comment: @MPW :both of them work ,but there was $\sqrt2 .x$ in the book

Comment: @MPW :https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pzlufomnmx $$\\there $$are both of them ,in one plot

Comment: It's a bit unsatisfying, but considering that all the functions here are well-behaved with minima around 0, the plot _is_ a proof. I'm sure someone will post a neat trick though.

Comment: I know the plot is proof , but i get stuck on this to find analytic method ...(any way thank you )

Comment: Look here if it can help https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B%7BSqrt%5B157%5D+-+Sqrt%5B2+%5D+x,++++Sqrt%5B2+x%5E2+%2B+2+x+%2B+1%5D+%2B+Sqrt%5B2+x%5E2+-+10+x+%2B+13%5D+%2B+++++Sqrt%5B2+x%5E2+-+22+x+%2B+73%5D%7D,+%7Bx,+-2,+6%7D%5D

Comment: @MPW $\sqrt{2x}$ would not even be defined for all real $x$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : True dat. Maybe $\sqrt{2x^2}$ instead, which is "nearly" $\sqrt{2}\cdot x$? I was hoping there would be a sort of similarity between the terms. I guess not. +1 for that.

Comment: The LHS is a convex function, hence if we manage to find a point such that the derivative vanishes, we have the actual minimum. What makes this exercise a bit difficult is that the inequality **is not** sharp: $\sqrt{157}$ is around $12.53$, while the actual minimum is around $13.1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a nice proof for $x\geq0$.

By Minkowski we obtain:
$$\sqrt 2 x + \sqrt {2{x^2} + 2x + 1} + \sqrt {2{x^2} - 10x + 13} + \sqrt {2{x^2} - 22x + 73}-\sqrt{157}=$$
$$=\sqrt 2\left(\sqrt{x^2} + \sqrt {{x^2} + x + \frac{1}{2}} + \sqrt {{x^2} - 5x + \frac{13}{2}} + \sqrt {{x^2} - 11x + \frac{73}{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{157}{2}}\right)=$$
$$=\sqrt 2\left(\sqrt{x^2} + \sqrt {\left(x+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\tfrac{1}{4}} + \sqrt {\left(-x+\tfrac{5}{2}\right)^2+ \tfrac{1}{4}} + \sqrt {\left(-x+\tfrac{11}{2}\right)^2+ \tfrac{25}{4}}-\sqrt{\tfrac{157}{2}}\right)\geq$$
$$=\sqrt 2\left(\sqrt{\left(x+x+\tfrac{1}{2}-x+\tfrac{5}{2}-x+\tfrac{11}{2}\right)^2+\left(0+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{5}{2}\right)^2}-\sqrt{\tfrac{157}{2}}\right)=$$
$$=13-\sqrt{157}>0.$$
We'll prove that for $x\leq0$ our inequality is also true.

Indeed, after replacing $x$ at $-x$ we need to prove that:
$$-\sqrt 2 x + \sqrt {2{x^2}-2x + 1} + \sqrt {2{x^2}+10x + 13} + \sqrt {2{x^2}+ 22x + 73}>\sqrt{157},$$ where $x\geq0.$

But $$\sqrt{2x^2-2x+1}=\sqrt{2\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$$
$$\sqrt{2x^2+10x+13}-\sqrt2x-\sqrt{11}=\frac{2x^2+10x+13-2x^2-2\sqrt{22}x-11}{\sqrt{2x^2+10x+13}+\sqrt2x+\sqrt{11}}>0$$ and $$\sqrt{2x^2+22x+73}\geq\sqrt{73}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\sqrt{11}+\sqrt{73}>\sqrt{157},$$ which is true.

Comment: wow! very very nice . wish  I vote +1000

Comment: @Khosrotash Tank you! But for $x<0$ my proof is still very ugly.

Comment: :I saw the problem again , there was $$\forall x\geq 0 $$

Comment: :Yes , please . I am learning ...I always enjoy of your ideas. thank again

Comment: I have found mistake in my proof for $x<0$ and I deleted it.